# Is there a time after eternity?

Tags: cosmology, time

Is it possible that there are instants of time which are located infinitely distant in the future? We all think of time as a real line, or perhaps, if the Big Bang is the beginning of time, then the nonnegative portion of the real line. But could it be that there are times after all finite time has passed?

Comment: I suggest asking this question in the philosophy SE community.

Comment: What experiment or observation do you propose to test your hypothesis?

Comment: The concept of *Malament–Hogarth spacetime* (see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malament%E2%80%93Hogarth_spacetime)) is a formalization in the language of general relativity of what OP is after. Consequently, I do not think that the question is off-topic, voting to reopen. (Although philosophy SE may also consider this question suitable).

Comment: I think of time as that which the clocks show. Clocks are a lot of things, but they are not eternal.

Comment: @A.V.S. All the wiki tells me is that M-H didn't know what time actually is and they are simply over-extrapolating a theory that doesn't know either.

Comment: Fair point, @JohnDoty, OTOH, we can't observe the very early universe either, and our expermental evidence regarding it is, by necessity, rather indirect.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't be surprised if the timeline isn't closed at $t=0$. That is, positive times exist, but there is no time zero. And perhaps the very earliest instants are not well-ordered, due to Heisenberg uncertainty applied to quantum gravity.

Comment: @JohnDoty:  Simple, just wait until time ends and then see what happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point is that "infinitely distant in the future" is a vague statement, so vague that any answer is impossible without an interpretation.

I try here to use the simplest interpretation in the general case of a spacetime without timelike Killing vectors (giving rise to horizons), using only the proper time intepretation (and not a Killing time interpretation).

From this perspective,  "infinitely distant in the future" means that **every** clock evolving  from the initial event to the event "infinitely distant in the future" should measure an infinite interval of proper time to reach the latter.

Let $q$ be an event supposed to be infinitely far in the future of the event  $q_0$. Since $q$ stays in the future of $q_0$, it must be $q\in I^+(p)$.
By definition of $I^+$ there there exists a future directed timelike curve  $\mu :I \to M$ such that $\mu(s_0)=q_0$, $\mu(s_1)=q$, for some values $s_0,s_1 \in I$, $s_0<s_1$. The curve is at least  piecewise $C^1$ and therefore
$$T=\int_{s_0}^{s_1} \sqrt{-g(\dot{\mu}(s), \dot{\mu}(s))} ds <+\infty$$
because the integral is the sum of finite integrals (each of them is the integral of a continuous function on a compact interval). $T$ is the proper time measured along that curve by an ideal clock, and that interval of time is **finite**.
So, from this perspective the answer is negative.

The  **Malament–Hogarth spacetime** is not a counterexample in my view. In that spacetime (quoting by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malament%E2%80%93Hogarth_spacetime))   "there exists a worldline $\lambda$  and an event $q$ such that all events along $\lambda$  are a finite interval in the past of $q$, but the proper time along $\lambda$  is infinite." (See this [figure](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Penrose-diagram-of-an-analytically-extended-Kerr-Newman-spacetime-with-the-worldline-of_fig2_263029638) where $\lambda$ is indicated by $\gamma$.)

In other words every point on $\lambda$ is connected to $q$ by a curve $\mu$ of the type I wrote above.

**ADDENDUM**. After a discussion with @A.V.S. I have realized that there is  another possibility actually *against* my conclusion: It may happen that, even if  all timelike curves joining the two events are of finite length, the length of those curves (joining the same pair of events) may be  arbitrary large. However, this possibility is forbidden if the considered spacetime is *globally hyperbolic*. Global hyperbolicity is usually a basic requirement for considering a spacetime physically meaningful, especially in quantum field theory. But there are several interesting spacetimes which are not globally hyperbolic, like some maximal extensions of non-Schwarzschild black holes.  Malament–Hogarth spacetime in particular are *not* globally hyperbolic.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140196/discussion-on-answer-by-valter-moretti-is-there-a-time-after-eternity).